# How to connect to my Postgresql database on a Compute Engine from my Google App Engine app using host

Tags: database, postgresql, google-app-engine, go

I have been deploying my Go app on Google App Engine and that is nice. Then I created a Postgresql database on a Computing Engine with this beautiful setup document of Google: 
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-postgres

And I have created my Database and tables and thats all very nice.. The only thing I still don't know is, how do I connect to this Computing Engine from my App engine app?

In my Go code the following connection is made like this:

```
package core

import (
"database/sql"
"log"

_ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB

func ConnectDB(connectStr string) {

var err error
db, err = sql.Open("postgres", ("host=???? user=user password=pw   
dbname=dbtest sslmode=disable")

err = db.Ping()
checkErr(err)
...
```

Now I see thats Google nicely explains how this can be done for cloud SQL in here:https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/reference

But I want to know how I make this work for my Compute Engine with my PostgreSQL database aswell :(

**UPDATE 21-03-16:**

Yes I already changed it to the external ip address as host and now I see it actually connects with the database on the compute engine, HOWEVER I see why I was confused, the log and the site still show a Server error, this time saying the following in the log from the db.Ping error:

***panic: dial tcp [external ip address]:5432: operation not permitted***

There are already several standard firewalls with:
0.0.0.0/0 and a port numbers :80, :443 etc

Do I need to add an extra rule? And how should this rule look like? Is there more information somewhere where I can see how I should do this correctly?

**UPDATE 23-03**

To summarize: **I want to be "authorize" my Google App Engine app on the Compute Engine to connect to my Database. How do I do this?**

Somehow, this is not very clear from the google websites, eventhough this should be something trivial. I would expect clear information on the google compute\app engine site..

Now I am pretty much forced to work with CloudSQL

**Conclusion:**

I think it is required to use OAuth as is explained in the link provided in my own comment below

Comment: What is the address of your GCE instance? The external IP address is documented on the VM Instances Page -> External IP.

Comment: I have updated the problem, yes indeed you should connect to the external ip address. But now it complains about a: operation not permitted error towards this external ip address

Comment: Are you sure SSL is not enabled? That's a (very) bad idea if you're connecting remotely.

Comment: Yes I am sure that should be changed eventually, at this moment I just want some more information how this should be configured. I am able to connect with my PGadmin client from my local computer, so it should also be possible to connect AND perform queries on it, but apparently something still need to be configured for this..

Comment: What (exactly) are you entering in PGAdmin?

Comment: The same external ip:5432, with the same user\pw as I use in the code. The connection is not the problem, I can see that I am connected, but the error is given because I am performing a query in this Google App Engine code.

Comment: is there a way to "authorize" my app engine App on the compute engine where my DB is located?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/authorization

Comment: see also: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount